# Запятая при встрече соединительного союза И и подчинительного союза

Tags: союзов

3) запятая ставится и перед союзом и, и после него, если он соединяет два простых предложения (причем после придаточной части не следует вторая часть двойного союза):

Крепкий был человек Гуляев, и, когда он вернулся на Урал, за ним тянулась блестящая слава миллионера (М.-С.);

Но разве после союза и идет простое предложение?

Answer (score 2):

Сравните:

*Крепкий был человек Гуляев, **и**, когда он вернулся на Урал, **за ним тянулась блестящая слава миллионера*** (здесь И соединяет простые предложения).

*Крепкий был человек Гуляев, **и когда он вернулся на Урал, то за ним тянулась блестящая слава миллионера*** (здесь И соединяет простое и сложноподчиненное предложение).

Это формулировки из учебников по пунктуации. Видимо, они условны и служат одной цели: научить различать предложения таких типов, чтобы расставлять знаки в соответствии с правилами.

Comment: Второй вариант смотрится лучше. Гораздо лучше - ведь паузы после *и*/перед *когда* мы не делаем. А запятая всегда означает паузу.

Comment: Тут дело не в паузах, а в структурах и смыслах. Придаточные предложения вообще произносятся без пауз, а запятыми выделяются. Крепкий был человек Гуляев и когда он вернулся на Урал - это уже третий смысл.

Comment: Союз *и* в окружении двух запятых смотрится дико, согласитесь. Поэтому без ущерба для *смыслов и структур* вторую запятую мы можем опустить. Она не нужна.

Comment: Не соглашусь.

Comment: Так и запишем.

Comment: Крепкий был человек Гуляев, и, когда он вернулся на Урал, за ним тянулась блестящая слава миллионера (здесь И соединяет простые предложения).

Крепкий был человек Гуляев, и когда он вернулся на Урал, то за ним тянулась блестящая слава миллионера (здесь И соединяет простое и сложноподчиненное предложение).

не пойму, почему из-за изъятия ТО союз И присоединяет сложноподчиненное.

Answer (score 1):

Союз "и" соединяет две части сложного предложения "Крепкий был человек Гуляев, и за ним тянулась блестящая слава миллионера", поэтому перед "и" запятая нужна

Comment: Первое предложение: Крепкий был человек Гуляев
Второе предложение:когда он вернулся на Урал, за ним тянулась блестящая слава миллионера.

оно же не простое, а сложноподчиненное.

выходит, И соединяет не два простых предложения, а простое и сложноподчиненное?

Comment: Крепкий был человек Гуляев, и, когда он вернулся на Урал, за ним тянулась блестящая слава миллионера (здесь И соединяет простые предложения).

Крепкий был человек Гуляев, и когда он вернулся на Урал, то за ним тянулась блестящая слава миллионера (здесь И соединяет простое и сложноподчиненное предложение)

есть разница в смыслах этих предложений?

Answer (score 1):

При оформлении предложения  возможны два варианта:  союз И соединяет простое предложение с ГЛАВНЫМ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЕМ в составе СПП или с ЦЕЛЫМ СПП, что зависит от наличия двойного союза.

А. НЕТ ДВОЙНОГО СОЮЗА

(1) Крепкий был человек Гуляев, и, когда он вернулся на Урал,  за ним тянулась блестящая  слава миллионера.

Возможна ПЕРЕСТАНОВКА  придаточного: (1) «Крепкий был человек Гуляев, и за ним тянулась блестящая  слава миллионера, когда он вернулся на Урал».  Союз И соединяет простое предложение и главное предложение в составе СПП. В этом случае придаточное предложение обособляется с двух сторон.

Б. ДВОЙНОЙ СОЮЗ

(2) «Крепкий был человек Гуляев, и когда он вернулся на Урал, то за ним тянулась блестящая  слава миллионера».
Перестановка придаточного невозможна при наличии двойного подчинительного союза КОГДА…ТО, союз И соединяет простое предложение и СПП.

ПО ПОВОДУ  ПАУЗ И ЗАПЯТЫХ

1) Конечно же, не всякая запятая обозначается паузой. Знаки препинания могут ставиться в соответствии с  принципами: интонационно-грамматическим  (паузы соответствуют запятым), или  только с интонационным, или только с грамматическим.

2) Интонация предложения определяется его  «старшей» структурой (поэтому в сложном предложении нельзя интонационно выразить более простые конструкции: вводные слова, деепричастные обороты   др.).  Надо понимать, что возможности интонации по своей природе  являются ограниченными.

3) Интонационно варианты (1) и (2) не различаются:  предложение состоит из трех фраз, но при этом между первым простым предложением  и СПП делается увеличенная пауза, позволяющая понять, что  предложение состоит из этих двух частей.

4) На письме знаки препинания   должны нам помочь ПРАВИЛЬНО ПРОЧИТАТЬ предложение. Двойной  союз  уже обозначает конструкцию грамматически,  в этом случае  достаточно одной запятой перед союзом И.

5) При отсутствии двойного союза мы имеем три предикативные основы, поэтому  следует дополнительно обозначить, что придаточное относиться к третьей части предложения, имея  при этом определенную степень свободы в своем положении. Можно считать, что это чисто графическое оформление СПП,  в устной речи оно интонационно не выражено.